# selinux denying haproxy connections?

Tags: haproxy, selinux

I'm seeing these messages popping up in syslog:

```
Mar 10 12:51:35 db1 kernel: [5851729.958138] type=1400 audit(1457614295.823:2925931): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=801 comm="haproxy" dest=7778 scontext=system_u:system_r:haproxy_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:interwise_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

Does this mean that SELinux is denying connections to haproxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You could try running:

`setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any 1`

as root to enable connection for haproxy.

Comment: Work like a charm for me on centos 7.

Comment: indeed this is the solution. fedora 25 here

Comment: one can pre/post-check the status and existence of selinux rules with:
semanage boolean -l | grep haproxy